# panda loc with mulitple boolean conditions to create subset

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to create a subset dataframe containing all the rows when the row 'Name' is Sam or Frank. I run the following code but it returns no data:

```
df.loc[(df["Name"] == 'Sam') & (df["Name"] =='Frank'), :]
```

How can I change the code to work?

Comment: remove the ,:      you should get your result. you could also use df.query('Name.isin(["Sam","Frank"])'). And yes, following on from Allolz comment, switch & to |

Comment: Because it's impossible for the name to be simultaneously 'Frank' and 'Sam'. Use `.isin(['Frank', 'Sam'])` if you want either.